# How to append N elements to a List?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I build a list:

```
int TOTAL = 10;
List<MyObject> myList = myOtherList.Select
            (s => new MyObject
            {
                Prop1 = s.prop1
            })
            .ToList<MyObject>();
```

Here `myList` have M elements (M = myList.Count())

I need to append `N` elements to myList so that the `myList` have TOTAL elements, in other words `N+M = TOTAL`.

How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Where are you getting N elements from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get "n" elements from `myOtherList` and add them to `myList`.

```
myList.AddRange(myOtherList.Select(s => new MyObject { Prop1 = s.prop1 }).Take(n));
```

The nice thing about [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) is that if there are not enough elements in `myOtherList`, it won't cause an error - it'll just get all the elements.

> If *count* exceeds the number of elements in *source*, all elements of *source* are returned.
>
> If *count* is less than or equal to zero, *source* is not enumerated and an empty IEnumerable is returned.

Comment: Take is definately a way to go. Didn't think of it.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep adding new items until you hit your desired size:

```
while (myList.Count < TOTAL)
{
    myList.Add(NewItem);
}
```

Comment: the OP want a Linq approach

Comment: Where do you take that from? It’s not obvious to me; and a simple loop is certainly the simpler and more direct approach here.

Comment: from the tags and the way  he is trying to do it

Comment: What they “tried to do” is how they build the original list. OP now wants to add `N` more elements to that list, so its total size is `TOTAL`.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ approach:

```
myList.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, TOTAL - myList.Count).Select(i => myList2[i]));
```

just remember to check whether the `myList.Count` is smaller than TOTAL, and `myList2` has enough elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here  a full example illustratting how you  can achieve this with a single line of code

```
list.AddRange(list2.Take(total - list.Count));
```

**full example**

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new MyObject() {Id = i}
                );
        }

        List<MyObject> list2 = new List<MyObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            list2.Add(new MyObject() {Id = i});
        }

        int total = 10;
        list.AddRange(list2.Take(total - list.Count));
    }

    class MyObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use myList.AddRange() with a limited list in parameter or use myList.Add() in the ForEach Linq.

```
int TOTAL = 10;
List<MyObject> myList = something;
if (myList < TOTAL)
{
    myOtherList.Select
        (s => new MyObject
        {
            Prop1 = s.prop1
        })
        .ToList<MyObject>()
        .Take(TOTAL - myList.Count)
        .ForEach(ob => myList.Add(ob));
}
```

or

```
int TOTAL = 10;
List<MyObject> myList = something;
if (myList < TOTAL)
{
    myList.AddRange(myOtherList.Select
        (s => new MyObject
        {
            Prop1 = s.prop1
        })
        .ToList<MyObject>()
        .Take(TOTAL - myList.Count));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatN<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> source2, int maxSize)
{
    if (maxSize == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "maxSize cannot be zero", "maxSize");

    var sourceCount = source.Count();

    if (sourceCount > maxSize)
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "source has more elements than the given maxSize");

    if (sourceCount + source2.Count() < maxSize)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            "source and source2 has combined, more elements than the given maxSize");

    return source.Concat(source2.Take(maxSize - sourceCount));
}
```

> - If the number of items in `source` exceeds the given `maxSize`, an exception is throwen.
> - If the number of items in `source` + `source2` is    less than the given `maxSize`, an exception is throwen.

Usage:

```
var number1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
var number2 = Enumerable.Range(100, 10);

var number12 = number1.ConcatN(number2, 15);

Console.WriteLine("Length = {0} | Sum = {1}",
    number12.Count(), number12.Sum());

// Output: "Length = 15 | Sum = 555"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
myList.AddRange()
```

this is used to add a list to your existing list. (It'll work with any IEnumerable of the same type as the existing list).

Marked down... ooooh I didn't realise we had to write entire solutions for people and there was me thinking that I was wise spending 10 years learning software development when I could have just used stack overflow instead of my brain